# I can't close a question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Maybe my powers are fading, but I can't seem to close [What does this javascript code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934653/what-does-this-javascript-code-do#question) as a duplicate of [Can someone decrypt this javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556853/can-someone-decrypt-this-javascript) or [Javascript in the adress bar. is this malicious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634159/javascript-in-the-adress-bar-is-this-malicious)  The question has seven close votes already, three of them mine.

That question is also displaying the `add / show 1 more comment` message, but there is no other comment.  The auto-inserted duplicate comment with a link was deleted the first time I tried to close the question, but the message is still there.

Comment: 'tis being dealt with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just needed someone *man enough* to do it evidently, sorry!

It was an unrelated bug that manifested here as a result of a build a few minutes ago, fixed and deployed since this was obviously an urgent one.